# How to pass interface parameter to call a service method?

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, web-services

I have a project library which has a role as a service. It consists of:

1. An Interface:

```
public interface IManageApplicationServiceInterface : IProcessQ<IManageApplicationServiceEntity>
{
    void createMyApp(IManageApplicationServiceEntity serviceEntity);
}
```

2. A service class that implements the interface above:

```
[Export(typeof(IProcessQ))]
[ProcessMetaData("My API Service Interface", "F756B100-5B85-4877-9EF6-BB53727371BB",PluginType.ServiceInterface, typeof(IManageApplicationServiceEntity))]
public class ManageApplicationServiceInterface : IManageApplicationServiceInterface
{
    public void Execute(IEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void Execute(IManageApplicationServiceEntity serviceEntity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void createMyApp(IManageApplicationServiceEntity applicationData)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Debug("Create may app method - Starts");
            //build something to make an api call 
            //apiURL
            //create a JObject with adding 2 properties
            //prepare a httpContent
            var content = new StringContent(jsonCreateApp.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            //add default request headers for httpClient object
            //get client response
            var clientResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(apiURL, content).Result;
            //If the API call is success then read the response otherwise throw exception
                if (clientResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var apiResult = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(clientResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    Logger.Debug("Create App method - Reading response");

                    response.Add("id", apiResult["id"].ToString());
                    response.Add("createMyAppETagID", removeDoubleQuote(clientResponse.Headers.ETag.ToString()));
                    response.Add("responseMyApp", apiResult.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Create App method Error - Status Code" + clientResponse.StatusCode + "ReasonPhrase - " + clientResponse.ReasonPhrase);
                    throw new ArgumentException("Create App method Error - Status Code" + clientResponse.StatusCode + "ReasonPhrase - " + clientResponse.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                Logger.Debug("Create My App method - Ends");
                return response;
            Logger.Debug("Create create My App - Ends");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Expection in Create My App method - " + ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }    
}
```

I'm going to call createMyApp web service method from a web console or a web application. I used a 
web application to call it in Page_Load

```
IManageApplicationServiceEntity manageApplicationServiceInterface;
ds.createMyApp(manageApplicationServiceInterface);
```

When hover on ds.createMyApp Visual Studio says: "Front End should supply the input json". Does it need a JObject and convert the object to IManageApplicationServiceEntity type before passing it? 
And when hover on the interface variable it says: "Used unassigned local variable manageApplicationServiceInterface"

How can I prepare for the interface parameter to pass to the service method createMyApp to call it?
Hope get help. Many appreciate!

Comment: Are you creating object of IManageApplicationServiceEntity type? This two lines of code are all of your service usage?

Comment: Right, that two lines in the page_load to use the service. But I'm not aware of the way to call it. Please help me out. Many thanks!

Comment: @ElConrado ds is an instance of the service class ManageApplicationServiceInterface ds = new ManageApplicationServiceInterface();

Comment: Ok, from this two lines of code where you initializing manageApplicationServiceInterface (which is IManageApplicationServiceEntity type) object? I am not asking about ds object, I am asking about object which is passed by createMyApp parameter